# Getting error in JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Code:

```
var str = '/tip -a 20 send 20tips to   chinu';
var parts = str.match(/^\/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*(.*)/).slice(1);
console.log(parts);
```

Output:

```
["tip", "-a", "20", "send 20tips to   chinu"]
```

I want to change the text :

```
var str = '/tip 20 send 20tips to   chinu';
```

The result should be `["tip", "20", "send 20tips to   chinu"]` but i am getting `["tip", "20", "send", "20tips to   chinu"]`

Please help me.

**EDIT:**

variable `str` contains dynamic text. It may be `/tip 20` or `/tip -a 20`
check http://myshowcam.com/NewSite/chat-room/chinu type `/help` command you will get `/tip` command instructions.

Comment: Again: TIP or PRICE?

Comment: its tip. Yesterday I was  posting same question. but not getting any satisfied answer.

Comment: If it's dynamic, then you should not use `(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s`. So, by default, it matches three words

Comment: Because you were not giving the full story. Please refrain from posting the same question again, instead add information to your original question

Comment: In this code "/tip -a 20 send 20tips to   chinu" you have 3 "single" words before "send 20tips to   chinu", in this one "/tip 20 send 20tips to   chinu", you have only 2 "words", the "-a" is missing. So the output is correct. Checkout this here https://regex101.com/

Comment: So split on space, if second parm is -a or-m or whatever use the above regex, otherwise use a shorter one

Comment: And where is this dynamic text coming from ? Is it generated by you ? Maybe you can create a pattern and create a regex for the pattern defined by you

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu i have just given static text. Actually this is dynamic. Please check http://myshowcam.com/NewSite/chat-room/chinu and type /help in the chatbox

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu after putting `/help` command one popup will showing on the right side. Check `/tip` command

Comment: @mplungjan I have edited my question. please check above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with optional 2nd part with `filter(Boolean)`:

```
// case 1
var str = '/tip -a 20 send 20tips to   chinu';
var parts = 
 (str.match(/^\/(tip)\s+(-[apm]\s+)?(\S+)\s*(.*)/) || ['tip', 'tip']).
      filter(Boolean).slice(1);
//=> ["tip", "-a ", "20", "send 20tips to   chinu"]

// case 2
str = '/tip 20 send 20tips to   chinu';
parts = 
 (str.match(/^\/(tip)\s+(-[apm]\s+)?(\S+)\s*(.*)/) || ['tip', 'tip']).
      filter(Boolean).slice(1);
//=> ["tip", "20", "send 20tips to   chinu"]

// case 3
str = '/tip';
parts = 
 (str.match(/^\/(tip)\s+(-[apm]\s+)?(\S+)\s*(.*)/) || ['tip', 'tip']).
      filter(Boolean).slice(1);
//=> ["tip"]
```

Comment: `var newStr = str.match(/^\/(\S+)\s+(-[apm]\s+)?(\S+)\s*(.*)/).filter(Boolean).slice(1);`   I have just modified your code. Now I am typing only `/tip` without any price, type and message. Still I am getting error.

Comment: I am using above input string which you have written. If i am entering only `/tip` i want to validate. I have used your code. But i am getting `TypeError: str.match(...) is null` error

Comment: You are right. But i was saying to validate. This is a text field. User may put any word. So i need to validate. If there is no word after `/tip` it says `Error: Enter your tips amount` if there are `/tip -a` it says `Error: please enter valid number`. I have tried yesterday. Unable to complete. I am very week in regular expression. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: My tips format is -  `/tip [optional -a,-p,-m] 20 [optional_comments]` or `/tip 20 [optional_comments]`

Comment: Yes starting with `/tip` in other case it will change. Please check http://myshowcam.com/NewSite/chat-room/chinu type `/help` you will able to see the commands

Comment: Yes you are right. But i don't want to see any JavaScript error.

Comment: When I type only `/tip` getting blank. but I need to show `[ "tip" ]` instead of `[  ]`

Comment: `case 3`  I need `[ "tip" ]` dynamic for other commands. you have make this static.

Comment: I am entering `/tip -a 20` getting space after `-a`

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var str1 = '/tip -a 20 send 20tips to   chinu';
    var str2 = '/tip 20 send 20tips to   chinu';
    var str3 = '/tip 20';
    
    function getArr(str) {
        if (str.split(" ")[1].indexOf("-")==0) return str.match(/^\/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*(.*)/).slice(1);
        else return str.match(/^\/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*(.*)/).slice(1);
    }
    alert(getArr(str1))
    alert(getArr(str2))
    alert(getArr(str3))
```

Comment: Hi, Your code is working fine. But I am getting error when type only `/tip` If I will typing `/tip` it will saying `Error: Please enter tips amount`

Comment: Error  - `TypeError: str.split(...)[1] is undefined
 

if (str.split(" ")[1].indexOf("-")==0) return str.match(/^\/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+...

 `

Comment: Two cases this is not working 1st `/tip` and 2nd are `/tip -any_word`

Comment: They work. try test. If the strings are wrong, give me more examples

Comment: I do not understand what you enter to get errors. It should not be possible to enter `/tip` only - it must be followed by an amount. no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if your dynamic text always contains `-` before optional switch

```
^\/(\S+)\s+(-\S+)?\s*(\S+)\s*(.*)
```